# Face keeps disappearing

Tags: modeling

I'm using the source engine with blender, however, my face keeps disappearing, how do I fix it? 
The disappearing faces are red, you can also download the blend

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your face an NGon, does it have more than 4 sides? It looks like the Source Engine doest like ngons. Try making your model all composed of triangles and 4 sided faces only

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: That is generally something you strive for while building your model so it is planed that way from scratch. Here is a guide that may help you http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/ For you case now may be too late for a simple solution without too much work, try first using a triangulate modifier and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: One other common cause for disappearing faces that may be affecting your model is incorrecty facing normals. Try recalculating your mesh normals be selecting all faces and pressing Ctrl+N to make all normals consistent

Comment: It appears like you have reversed normals.